# Any window overlay on windows

Tags: c#, windows, 2d

I am willing to write a depixelizer for pixel art games(old ones played using dosbox and new ones) so I have to get the picture from the app, process it and show the result and do it about 30 times a second. My preferred language is C#.

I know there is a `public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)` function usually used to take a screenshot but using it I will have to create another window and show the result on it (and I'm not sure about speed of this solution) while I would like to create something like a filter above original app window. (Like Nvidia Freestyle can do)

Comment: So... What is the question?

Comment: Is there a way to make an app which will overlay any window and postprocess image on it? Or what is the fastest way to get an image of any window in windows using c#?